# DataTaskPublisher is not executed

Tags: swift, combine

I have a rather odd problem. All the code below does is post json to a url. I use the same code in other parts of the project. For some reason though, this specific code's DataTaskPublisher doesn't execute (as in: doesn't seem to do anything at all. It doesn't even throw an error message, none of the print's in the pipeline print). The last sign of life I get is from print(arr). However, if I very often press the button in the app which executes this code then eventually a single call *might* get through, so not very often. Other network code in the app always executes without any issues. Also, I know the url can be called because I keep testing with Postman. Does someone have any good ideas how to debug this? Any leads are much appreciated!

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import FirebaseAuth

class HistoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [History]()
    
    private var publisher: AnyCancellable?
    

    func saveData(dataArr: [Bool]){
        
        let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
        currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(false, completion: { idToken, error in
            
            var json = History()
            
            var arr: [Int] = []
            for (index, value) in dataArr.enumerated() {
                if(value) { arr.append(index) }
            }
            
            json.user_id = currentUser?.uid ?? "1"
            json.dataArr = arr
            json.created_client = DateHelper().ISOString
            
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let data = try! encoder.encode(json)
            
            let url = URL(string: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("Bearer "+String(idToken!), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpBody = data
            
            print(arr)
            
            self.publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                .tryCatch({ error -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error> in
                    print("In the tryCatch")
                    throw error
                })
                //.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(
                    receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        print("completion")
                        switch completion {
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("SINKERRORPOST")
                            print(error)
                        case .finished:
                            print("SINKSUCCESSPOST")
                        }
                    },
                    receiveValue: { repo in
                        print("DONEPOST")
                    }
                )
               
            
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `.breakpoint()` before the `tryCatch` and see what happens.

Comment: I'm presuming you're calling `saveData` from somewhere? Have you checked that `currentUser` is not `nil`?